# Javascript AJAX error update

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tengo un problema resulta que estoy utilizando ajax, ya logre implementarlo en insertar, eliminar y leer pero no logro implementarlo para update no se si me puedan ayudar.

El archivo editar.php esta bien ya que funciona, ya que me trae los datos a un modal sin problema
Nombre: **editar.php**

```
<?php

include "model/conexion.php";
$edit_id = $_POST['edit_id'];
$sentencia = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?;");
$sentencia->execute([$edit_id]);
$var_productos = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editar producto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form" action="post">
        <div class="form-row">
        <input id="edit_id" value="<?php echo $var_productos->id ?>">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="">Producto</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="producto" id="edit_producto" value="<?php echo $var_productos->producto; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="">Codigo</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" id="edit_codigo" value="<?php echo $var_productos->codigo; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="">Valor unidad</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="valor_unidad" id="edit_valor_unidad" value="<?php echo $var_productos->valor_unidad; ?>">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="">Stock</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="stock" id="edit_stock" value="<?php echo $var_productos->stock; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Nombre: **update.php**

```
<?php 
include "model/conexion.php";
$edit_id = $_POST['edit_id'];
$codigo = $_POST['edit_codigo'];
$producto = $_POST['edit_producto'];
$stock = $_POST['edit_stock'];
$valor_unidad = $_POST['edit_valor_unidad'];

$sentencia = $bd->prepare("UPDATE productos SET codigo = ?, producto = ?, stock = ?, valor_unidad = ? WHERE id = ?;");

$resultado = $sentencia->execute([$codigo, $producto, $stock, $valor_unidad, $edit_id]);
?>
```

Archivo: **index.php** Solo voy a poner el respectivo ajax

```
    $(document).on("click", "#update", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var edit_producto = $("#edit_producto").val();
      var edit_codigo = $("#edit_codigo").val();
      var edit_valor_unidad = $("#edit_valor_unidad").val();
      var edit_stock = $("#edit_stock").val();
      var update = $("#update").val();
      var edit_id = $("#edit_id").val();

/* alert(edit_producto);
alert(edit_codigo);
alert(edit_valor_unidad);
alert(edit_stock);
alert(edit_id); */

      $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          edit_id: edit_id,
          edit_producto: edit_producto,
          edit_codigo: edit_codigo,
          edit_valor_unidad: edit_valor_unidad,
          edit_stock: edit_stock,
          update: update
        },
        success: function(data) {
          fetch();
          $("#show").html(data);
        }
      }) 

    });
```

El error que me lanza la consola es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se por que no me trae ningun dato realmente e dado vueltas como por 3 horas y no doy con el error. Es evidente que la cadena no trae nada ya que cuando llega a post nunca se impre algun dato, incluso la consola me lo dice.

Los datos me los lleva hasta la funcion JS, pero donde no entran es en el arreglo data:

Comment: Saludos. El `$.ajax is not function` pudiera ser por faltar cargar el *.js* (verifica se cargan por cualquier cosa) de **jQuery** respectivo; aunque  si fuese esto fallaría por ejemplo en `$("#edit_producto").val()` (y así por el  estilo en cualquier `$` que tuvieses. Otra cosa que debes corroborar es que la ruta/archivo `update.php` este correcto respecto al **index.php** donde se invoca; así mismo al **update.php** le hace falta al menos un `echo` o `print` que como tal "escriba" lo que se devolverá. Espero la revisión de algo de lo mencionado te sirva.

Comment: justo cuando publique el error me di cuenta que la falla es el jquery, estoy usando la version slim de jquery y no la min este era el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es chistoso pero a los 10 minutos de escribir la falla encontre que es problema de jquery.

error: la version slim de jquery tiene ese error

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

solucion: cambiar a una version que no sea slim

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```